No sclk with pi 5 spi0 and spidev
I'm trying to write to a spi device using a pi-5. The actual device doesn't matter - it's not working and i've simplified everything so my logic analyser is connected directly to the gpio pins (spi0). There is no activity on sclk (GPIO 11). The other spi pins look ok.
I'm using spidev and a simple python program to debug. In case there might be some issue with cpol/cpha (unlikely to stop sclk) the program varies this to look at all options.
sclk does toggle - but it is not as expected - it will sometimes wrap the spi frame (low with cs -then high at the end of the frame) - it also sometimes wraps MOSI - low at the start of the data-bits and high at the end - but it does not toggle to frame the changes to MOSI. I've tried 2 different pi's
Any idea what I might be missing?
pinctrl 9-11
 9: a0    pn | hi // GPIO9 = SPI0_MISO
10: a0    pn | hi // GPIO10 = SPI0_MOSI
11: a0    pn | hi // GPIO11 = SPI0_SCLK

import spidev
import time

# Open SPI device (bus 0, device 0)
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)  # SPI0, CS0 (chip select 0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000  # Set SPI speed to 1 MHz

# Try different SPI modes
for mode in range(4):
    spi.mode = mode
    print(f"Testing SPI mode: {mode}")
    to_send = [0xAA, 0x33]
    spi.xfer(to_send)
    time.sleep(1)  # Short delay to observe the signal


You have posted some code BUT no diagnostics or connection details.

"Any idea what I might be missing?" possibly an understanding of SPI. "sclk does toggle - but it is not as expected" what do you expect?

I'm pretty sure I understand SPI thanks - comments like this make people avoid asking questions. I explained what SKLK was doing relative to the CS/MOSI pin) - what diagnostics/connection details would be useful?
"(sclk) will sometimes wrap the spi frame (low with cs -then high at the end of the frame) - it also sometimes wraps MOSI - low at the start of the data-bits and high at the end - but it does not toggle to frame the changes to MOSI."
I'm expecting sclk to toggle to frame the changes to MOSI - which it isn't doing.

Your comments (using colloquial language) don't make much sense. If you are using a scope post capture. Depending on mode clock phases vary i.e. normal SPI. Have you tried running a SPI loop back test or connecting a SPI device?

Given that there is no sclk - why would a loop back test be useful? I should really post an image to explain what i'm seeing with the spi signals. I've also made a bit of progress. I get a perfect spi frame (sclk included) below 500kHz - above that the sclk gradually loses duty-cycle and is gone completely above 1MHz. I would have expected clean SPI maybe as far as 20MHz with my setup - perhaps higher.

Just in case this helps someone else. The problem was rather silly - just the bandwidth of my logic analyser. Thanks for looking and for Milliways for taking the time to answer.
